# Why is there no subject in 'Consider these markets when looking for...'?

Tags: imperative-sentences

> Consider these markets when looking for places to sell your work.

shouldn't it use a subject such as *you*?

Comment: As @Peter says, this is an imperative, and we almost never express the subject with imperatives. When the addressee *is* expressed it is usually an introductory or concluding supplement outside the imperative clause, to attract someone's attention or emphasize a warning. *You ... stop!*  *Listen, you.*

Answer (score 4):

It is an **imperative sentence**.
The **you** is implied in this sentence since the speaker is telling the listener (**you**) to do something. It is similar to saying:

> Stop!

Meaning **you** stop.